# How can i make a list inside an embed?

Tags: discord.py

In the first example after bulkgiving role to several players. They are logged seperately. How do i make them as a list inside the embed ?

```py
@command(name="bulktake")
    @has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def bulktake_role(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], *, role: discord.Role):
        if not len(targets):
            await ctx.send("One or more required arguments are missing.")

        else:
            for target in targets:
                await target.remove_roles(role)

                embed = Embed(title="Roles Taken",
                              colour=role.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                fields = [("--------------------------------------", f"***{target.display_name}*** successfully removed from ***{role.name}*** role by ***{ctx.author.display_name}***", False)]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await ctx.send(f"***{target.display_name}*** successfully removed from ***{role.name}*** role by ***{ctx.author.display_name}***")
                await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

        await ctx.message.delete()
```

In the second example it's pretty much the same thing. Here i list members in the mentioned role. They are lsited seperately.

```py
    @command(name="list")
    async def search_member(self, ctx, role_name):
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == role_name, ctx.guild.roles)
        userlist = []

        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            if role in user.roles:
                userlist.append(user)

                embed = Embed(title="Members in Role",
                      colour=role.colour,
                      timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                fields = [("Name", str(user.display_name), True),]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                await ctx.send(f"{user.display_name} has the role {role.name}")
```

When i store them both examples in a list and then append the outputs i get no result. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. I've presented the code that works but outputs the results seperately. Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for a simple command to list members in a role.

Used:

- [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get) To get the role in guild using name
- [`Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20members#discord.Role.members) To get a list of all role members.
- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) Returns a index and element for the list

[image]

```py
@bot.command(name="list")
async def search_member(ctx, *, role_name):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Members in Role",
                          colour=role.colour,
                          timestamp=dt.datetime.utcnow())

    for index, member in enumerate(role.members):
        embed.add_field(name=f'Name {index+1}',
                        value=member.mention, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you very much!